# AWS EB and S3: DL and manipulate archive content from the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I am developing a web-app which will be hosted in an AWS EB. So far, I am done with the entire back-end, and am currently working on the build for deployment. 
One thing bothers me however: my back-end accesses data from an AWS S3 Bucket, downloads the files locally (!), works it's magic on it and uploads it to a different bucket. 
Since the data being downloaded is being downloaded in a local folder on my computer which won't be available once deployed, how can or should I modify this to make it run in the AWS EB instance? I absolutely need to DL the files (archives) to extract and modify them. How can I achieve this in the cloud ? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Any help would be appreciated, please be gentle I'm kind of new to the entire EE world ...

Comment: "Works its magic" means what actually happens? Can you explain the process in brief?

Comment: ... it downloads the archives from S3, extracts their content, does a lot of manipulating of the files like reporting, formatting [...] before uploading the files with the extracted and manipulated data into a different Bucket within S3

Comment: Ok instead of Local run those process on a EC2 instance and and do the import export of the data from S3 using AWS CLI.

Comment: ok I'll try that thank you very much!